# MassTransit Bus.Publish calls SendObserver

Tags: masstransit

I have noticed that when i call Bus.Publish my SendObserver is beeing called along with my PublishObserver. In my original scenario i use the observers for some debug logging where i noticed that when i call Publish both the PublishObserver and the SendObserver is called with the same message. The example code below reproduces the scenario:

```
public class YourMessage { public string Text { get; set; } }

public class SendObserver : ISendObserver {
    public Task PreSend<T>(SendContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task PostSend<T>(SendContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message Sent, Id: {context.MessageId}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task SendFault<T>(SendContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class PublishObserver : IPublishObserver
{
    public Task PrePublish<T>(PublishContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task PostPublish<T>(PublishContext<T> context) where T : class
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Message Published, Id: {context.MessageId}");

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task PublishFault<T>(PublishContext<T> context, Exception exception) where T : class
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sbc =>
        {
            var host = sbc.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://rabbitmq/PublishSendTest"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            sbc.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "test_queue", ep =>
            {
                ep.Handler<YourMessage>(context =>
                {
                    return Console.Out.WriteLineAsync($"Received: {context.Message.Text}");
                });
            });
        });

        bus.ConnectSendObserver(new SendObserver());
        bus.ConnectPublishObserver(new PublishObserver());

        bus.Start();

        bus.Publish(new YourMessage { Text = "Hi" });

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadKey();

        bus.Stop();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Press any key to exit
Message Sent, Id: ac4f0000-3051-1065-bbe5-08d6335c9e05
Message Published, Id: ac4f0000-3051-1065-bbe5-08d6335c9e05
Received: Hi
```

Is this the expected behaviour? If so what can i do to determine if it acutally was a Publish call that created the message?

I used version 5.1.5

Comment: Does the same thing happen with the InMemory transport? I'm trying to remember why this decision was made, and honestly trying to remember which decision was made. I believe it was that all published messages are also _sent_, since Publish is a type of send, but I can't recall right now.

Comment: No. With the InMemory transport only the PublishObserver is called.

Comment: So it sounds like an issue with only some of the transports.

Comment: With Azure Service bus transport Send get called twice with the same message. So i get the following output:

Messaged Sent, Id: ac4f0000-3051-1065-5d03-08d634387288
Messaged Sent, Id: ac4f0000-3051-1065-5d03-08d634387288
Messaged Published, Id: ac4f0000-3051-1065-5d03-08d634387288
Received: Hi

Comment: Not surprising. I’ll create an issue to track the effort to get these ironed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inconsistent observer issue should be resolved in the develop builds, and a test has been created to verify the behavior on the supported transports. Once released, the send observer should only be called on an actual `Send`, and the publish observer should only be called on an actual `Publish`.

Thanks for bringing this up, I'm not sure how it got out of whack.

Comment: I ran my testprogram with 5.1.5.1682-develop and  it worked as expected. :-)